# Java IP Validator

Tags: java, actionlistener, validation, actionevent

So i am trying to create a Validator for a button which must check 3 textfields where one of them is a IP address. So basically the user has to enter the full IP address himself/herself.

So i have run into a unwanted syntax error, which i am sure is caused because of the textfield.

I tried converting the textfield into a string and then go through the validation but that just seems to make it worse

```
private class theValidator implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {           
        String textIP = txfIP.getText();
        txfIP.setInputVerifier(new InputVerifier() {
            Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\."+
                    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\." +
                    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\." +
                    "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\b");

            public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
                boolean inputOK = verify(input);
                if (inputOK) {
                    return true;
                } 
                else {
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
                    return false;
                }
            }
            public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
                JTextField field = (JTextField) input;
                Matcher m = pat.matcher(field.getText());
                return m.matches();
            }
        });
}
}
```

Comment: You need semi-colon there to complete statement. Have you tried what compiler suggesting? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I do not see a closing brace for `txfIP.setInputVerifier(..`

I'd recommend to use some editors like Eclipse to code, so that you will find it easy to catch errors like this.

2) As far as regex for validating ip address, you can try this. Hope that helps.

```
IPADDRESS_PATTERN = 
        "^([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\." +
        "([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";
```

Comment: The one i i have a comment at is the the clossing bracket for it

Comment: No, you are missing ");" The curly brace is for "new InputVerifier() {.. "

Comment: yeah i found out right after texting it, thanks :) guess i should stop programing after looking at code for Straight 10 hours ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you'll use an existing IP validator like the one from Apache:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/InetAddressValidator.html